# Receber dois números positivos e repetir o intervalo entre eles com while?

Tags: javascript, while

Como fazer um programa JavaScript que recebe dois números positivos e repete o intervalo entre eles usando `while`?

```
var num1 = Number(window.prompt("Entre com primeiro numero"));
var num2 = Number(window.prompt("Entre com segundo numero"));

var numero = 0;

if( num1 >=0 && num2 >=0){

   while (numero>= num1 && numero >=num2){

      document.write (numero+" ");

      numero++;

   }

}
```

Comment: O que é repetir o intervalo entre eles? Repetir o que? O intervalo é inclusivo ou exclusivo? Nos dois lados?

Comment: As respostas ajudaram-te a resolver o problema?

Comment: Veja o [tour]. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (se tiver pontuação suficiente no momento).

Answer (score 1):

Há um problema na condição do `while` e não está considerando que os números não estão necessariamente ordenados. Pode fazer assim:

```js
var num1 = Number(window.prompt("Entre com primeiro numero"));
var num2 = Number(window.prompt("Entre com segundo numero"));
if (num1 >= 0 && num2 >= 0) {
    var i = Math.min(num1, num2);
    while (i <= Math.max(num1, num2)) console.log(i++);
}
```

Se preferir o `for` e mais "inteligente":

```js
var num1 = Number(window.prompt("Entre com primeiro numero"));
var num2 = Number(window.prompt("Entre com segundo numero"));
for (var i = Math.min(num1, num2); num1 >= 0 && num2 >= 0 && i <= Math.max(num1, num2); i++) console.log(i);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Sequence.js).

Answer (score 0):

Bom considerando que num2 é maior que num1 o código para poder fazer a contagem entre eles pode ser o seguinte:

```
var num1 = 3;
var num2 = 14;

var numero = num1;

if ((num1 >=0 && num2 >=0) && num1 < num2){
  while (numero <= num2){
    console.log(numero);
    numero++;
  }
}
```

Comment: mas e se nesse programa precisar ter 2 entradas usando prompt como que ficaria

Answer (score 0):

Podes comparar os numeros e defenir uma ordem para correr o `while`. Seria algo assim:

```js
var num1 = Number(window.prompt("Entre com primeiro numero"));
var num2 = Number(window.prompt("Entre com segundo numero"));

var start, end;
if (num1 > num2) (start = num2, end = num1);
else if (num1 < num2) (start = num1, end = num2);
else start = end = num1;

var i = start - 1;
while (i++ < end) {
    document.body.innerHTML += i + '<br>';
}
```

Para fazer o mesmo sem usar os extremos pode ser assim: https://jsfiddle.net/qr7v3aac/